# Can't click the buttons behind the DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Main"
android:background="@android:color/black" >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/about"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/calendar" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/okan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/calendar"
        android:background="@drawable/okanliyiz"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calendar"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I wrote the programmatic part of it and the `Drawer` works just fine, it's just that I cannot click the `ImageButton`s **behind** it. If I put the buttons in front I am able to click them but well, then the drawer is left behind and that's a terrible sight. What is the work-around for this? How can I both click the buttons behind the Drawer and see the Drawer in the front?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Navigation Drawer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) the `DrawerLayout` [should be the **root**](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) of your layout. It should have **only 2 children** - one that contains your "main content" - buttons, text fields, etc. And the other one should be the content of the drawer itself. Something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <RelativeLayout>
        <Button/>
        <EditText/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/drawer_list" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In addition:
The order of the 2 children is important due to the **Z-order** of the DrawerLayout (which is a ViewGroup). The list view should be declared after your main content so that it's ordered(and displayed) in front of it.

Comment: Hi, there. I assume you meant for the root element in your example layout to be `<DrawerLayout>`. My apologies if I've misread, but I've been using this question as a duplicate target for similar issues, and I just now noticed that.

Comment: Hi @MikeM. I think you are right. I haven't used a Drawer Layout recently but as far as I remember - yeah, the drawer layout should be the root. Thank you for the correction.